# android - possible to use in-app purchase for downloading content?

Tags: android, download, in-app-purchase

my question is quite simple :
does google have an in app purchase service which , after the purchasing process is complete , will download the purchased content ?
if not , is there any other alternative?

the reason for this is to make the app as small as possible instead of having all of the purchased content within the app .
a possible solution for this would be to use the extension library and download only a partial chunk from there , but that's too complex and for most devices the entire extension will be downloaded while downloading the app itself through the market.

Comment: once the user purchases, allow him to download the content from your server!?

Comment: sure this is possible, but i was thinking of google that will have both the content and the purchasing part...

Comment: good question, why close?

Comment: @zdd I didn't close the topic. I don't get why people are doing this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes.

It is also fully documented on android's developer repository, complete with guides on how to set it up, etc. Obviously if you utilize google they will take a cut. But if you made your own, you would still have to give a portion to your credit card processor. Best of luck:

http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/index.html

Amazon's android app market also offers a similar service.

**EDIT**

"---after the purchasing process is complete will download the purchased content" :: NO <-- to that part. You have to handle that with your own webserver. Only the original app content is hosted on Google Play for you.

Comment: are you sure? their documentation says differently , example:
http://developer.android.com/images/billing_arch.png , taken from: http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_overview.html

Comment: You'll have to excuse me. "---after the purchasing process is complete will download the purchased content" :: NO <-- to that part. You have to handle that with your own webserver. Only the original app content is hosted on Google Play for you.

Comment: so the answer to the question i've asked is simply "no, google doesn't have such a service" , right? if so , do you know of any other company that allows such a thing?

Comment: i see . maybe they are concerned of abuse and of legal problems.

Comment: How is this the correct answer? The answer to the original question is simply NO.

Comment: 5 years later, I don't even remember typing this answer.

Answer (score 0):

What I've frequently seen is to provide your extra content as another app download in the playstore, which then uses IPC to communicate/transfer that extra content to the main app.

I've seen video players, for example, request that you download a secondary app to get specific codecs.  Once the user has downloaded the codec app, and it has transferred its codecs to the video player app, the user can remove the codec app.

In your case, you'd have an extra step of performing a managed in-app purchase before your app would agree to communicate with the extra-content app.

It's a clunky user experience, but other than paying for a dedicated web host to serve your extra content, it is the only option at this point.

Comment: If you use the play store for the extra content (yet it's just extra apps), it would make more sense to make it a paid content there, instead of using in-app-purchases... Sadly, there isn't even an API to get the current list of "content-apps" for the "host" app (which uses them). I really hoped Google would add such an API, and I've even suggested them this : http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=76731