# I want to have in-app purchases for my android puzzle game that will download files with additional puzzles from Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase

Someone [asked a similar question that was closed 5 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341714/android-possible-to-use-in-app-purchase-for-downloading-content), and was told it's not possible at that time. Is this still the case? If so, how else can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try the following:

Include all puzzles in your free app

Set `boolean locked = true` and lock the payed puzzles if locked = true.

When your app starts, check if the app was purchased ([see documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate))

If the app was purchased, set locked = false.

Comment: The problem is I haven't created all the puzzles yet beyond what's included with the free app and 1 additional puzzle pack. I coded the app to hold up to 30 puzzle packs, but don't want to invest the considerable time it would take to make that many additional puzzles without knowing what the demand will be.

Comment: You could always add more puzzles later on in the form of app updates